# How to vlookup when lookup value has variations that need to be grouped into the same category

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, wildcard, vlookup

Every week I create a report using excel that pulls demand for certain product ID#s. I have a master list of ID#s and their respective group code. These are the specific IDs  I want to extract from the raw excel data sheet containing thousands of rows of data. I use a vlookup to match the ID# from the raw file with the ID# on my master list and my return value is the ID's group name (ex. A, B, C) which populates in the column next to the ID on the raw file(column D). Then on the raw file I filter column D and remove IDs that returned N/A so I can copy all of my specific IDs and their respective data.

The issue is that the ID# ending could change any time without my knowledge. For example, product ID A100-1A could show up the next week on the raw file as A100-1B. I need to be able to conduct a vlookup or some type of function with a wildcard so that I can return all values with the base A100-1 and have them match to their respective group name.

I can't add each variation of the ID onto my master list, as there's no way of knowing what variation could arise. I tried exploring wildcards, but it seems like they only work when used in a formula. Simply adding `*` onto my ID#s (A100-1*) on my master list doesn't work . I also cannot just type in `A100-1*` as my lookup value, as I have thousands of specific IDs I need to retrieve. Attached is an example of what I'm trying to achieve. D4 returns N/A because A100-1P is not on my master list. But the base ID matches: `A100-1` so I want D4 to populate with the group name A1. Appreciate any and all help!

[image]

Comment: Could you just get the position of the hyphen and then use left() it to search, so instead of searching the full name, you're searching everything upto the hyphen eg "A100-"?

Comment: If there are multiple group for ID `A100-1...` then what result do you expect?

Comment: Make a list of the unique id’s first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use (index(match()) instead of vlookup

```
=INDEX( Group range ;MATCH(#ID"without ending" & "*" ;#IDs range;0))
```

we can also use left() function to use old #ID to get answer

```
=INDEX( Group range ;MATCH(LEFT(#ID ; LEN(#ID)-1) & "*" ;#IDs range;0))
```